# How I can get lat and long of marker then store in firestore - flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore, marker

I want to get the latitude and longitude of the marker in this code for store this location in firebase

```
body: GoogleMap(
       zoomControlsEnabled: false,
       initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: latLng ,zoom: 14.34),
       markers: markers,
    //  onTap: _handleTap,
       onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
           _controller.complete(controller);
         },
       onCameraMove: (point){
         setState(() {
           markers.add(Marker(markerId: markerId,position: point.target)
           );
         });
         
       },
     ),
```

After get lat and long of new position of marker I want store new position in firestore

This my code

```
Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
 final markers = Set<Marker>();
 MarkerId markerId = MarkerId('parking');
 LatLng latLng = LatLng(32.5259483,35.8506622);

TextButton(onPressed: (){
                   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('parking_go_loc').add({
                         'name':'${name}',
                         'email':'${email}',
       'location' : GeoPoint(latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude),
       
                        });
                        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> LoginWoner()));
                 }
```

my packages

```
google_maps_flutter: 
 cloud_firestore: ^2.4.0
 location: ^4.2.0
 firebase_core :
```

But When I run this code it stores the first coordinates I put in code
It does not store the new coordinates of the marker after moving them and pressing the save button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to update the `latLng` variable to the new `LatLng` value in the `onCameraMove` callback.

Add this line `latLng = point.target` and your `onCameraMove` will be:

```dart
onCameraMove: (point){
  setState(() {
    markers.add(Marker(markerId: markerId,position: point.target)
    latLng = point.target;
  );
);
```